# A text version of the MySQL manual

Tags: mysql, documentation, manual

Always open in my editor is a tab with a text version of MySQL's manual (~100k lines in a readable layout), which is extremely helpful.
The version I have is very old (when 5.0 was still in beta), and this valuable text-file does not exist in mysql.com anymore.

Is there a newer version, or some tool that can create it out of the various existing formats?

Comment: If you do find it, please post a link here. I can really use it as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/ they have documentation in several formats and languages. For example pdf, chm, html,manpages and eclipse doc format.

If you want text only you could take the *"HTML Single page"*-version and save it as plain text using your browser.

Comment: The html is unreadable as plain text. Do you know of an app that converts to text and preserves the paragraphs' layout?

Comment: Firefox saves the text with formatting.

Comment: Firefox and IE both do a lousy job saving it as a text-file. Opera, on the other hand, generates a perfectly readable result.